# Altium vias and split plane

Tags: pcb-layers

Hello I'm routing PCB of my circuit using Altium and encounter a problem.

My PCB is multi-layer(4) board with two signal plane on each surface and two internal plane (Power Plane and Ground Plane)
the stack order is as follows :

1. Top layer signal plane
2. Power Plane
3. Ground Plane
4. Bottom layer signal plane
   from top to bottom
   One thing makes me a little bit confused and I'm stuck with it (Maybe it will be very simple question to you)

Suppose I want to add blind via from top layer to ground plane(1-3)
Then, the via will physically pass through power plane as well.
On some area, it will pass through split plane which is already conncected to other blind via as a net (As shown in the following figure)

[image]

1. Then, Should I avoid this area? My expectation is that : If I go ahead, two via get shorted and ground plane connected to 1-3 via will be 3.3 V plane
2. If I split the plane again and make no net plane and place 1-3 via on it, is it okay?

[image]

3. Does "no net" split plane means the plane is insulated?
4. Is each split plane electrically separated ? If so, can I make small
   split plane on power layer for signal transmission?

[image]

Comment: The via can pass through planes without making a connection. Altium (or any modern layout tool) will do this for you automatically based on netlist. Basically, for unconnected planes, altium will remove the copper on the plane around the via hole to create clearance. On layers where the via is connected, there will be a copper pad. Please note that blind vias will increase the cost of your board. If possible, you should do your board layout with all vias going from top to bottom.

Comment: blind vias limit the way the board is made, so a 1-3 via would require the very expensive and non-standard build process of add 3 foil on pre-preg to 1core2, drill, PTH, add 4 foil on pre-preg, drill, PTH. It makes for an unbalanced construction as well. Stick to 1-4 holes unless you really have to. Rethink, it could be made balanced, with 2core3 and 1 and 4 added as foil, but it still requires 2 drillPTH steps.

Comment: Two perfect answers, no way to accept or vote on any of them.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you for answering. You just teach me the very thing I wanted to know. I changed all of my blind vias into normal vias. Then, is it conventional way to place via from top to bottom and connect internal plane by assigning net?

Comment: @Neil_UK I've changed all of my blind vias. Thank you for teaching me why it is so costly

Comment: I am not an altium expert. But I think when you are routing a trace, if you start on a pad, the trace will automatically take on the net of the pad. If you change layers while routing, altium will automatically place a via, I think, and the via will automatically take on the net of the trace. So I think it may not be necessary to assign a net to the via most of the time. But if you place the via by itself, you may have to assign a net name to it. Play with it a little bit to see how it works.

Comment: If anyone wants to paste my comment into an answer, that is perfectly OK with me. If Neil doesn't mind, maybe you can work part of his answer in also.